# Removing back button text and centered text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm using a hack, in the App Delegate which removes all text from the Navigations Bar's back button.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-1000, -1000) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It just moves the back button text off the screen. So instead of:

```
| < PREVIOUS SCREEN   NEW   |
```

It should get

```
| <          NEW            |
```

But instead I get

```
| <                   NEW   |
```

This is because the space to the left of new is taken up with a 'phantom' `PREVIOUS SCREEN` ... it uses up the space, but doesn't actually display it.

Is there a way I can avoid this issue, in a way which effects the whole app?

Comment: the new offset pushing the nav bar title ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually reduce the text size as well:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:1.0] };

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -100.f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**EDIT**

In case you're using storyboards you can set the *Back Button* property of the NavigationItem to @" " (note the space). Kinda seems to work (quickly tested on iOS9).

[image]

Comment: I thought of doing this, but it also reduces the size of all other UIBarButtonItem's .. for instance a Done button on the right

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using storyboards